# Get min and count rows group by id

Tags: sql, postgresql

**EDIT I forget an important detail**

I have a postgresql table like this:

```
| id | n_1 | n_2 |
|  1 |   3 |   5 |
|  1 |   2 |   6 |
|  1 |   8 |   4 |
|  1 |   1 |   5 |
|  2 |   4 |   3 |
|  2 |   5 |   1 |
```

I want to get the min values and the count **count only if n_2 >= min(n_1)**:

```
| id | n_1 | n_2 | count |
|  1 |   1 |   4 |     4 |
|  2 |   4 |   1 |     0 |
```

The min number from n_1, min number from n_2 and count total **when n_2 >= min(n_1)** records from each id.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here how you can do it by grouping them by id :

```
select  id , min(n_1) ,min(n_2), count(case when n_2 >= min_n_1 then 1 end)
from ( select *, min(n_1) over (partition by id) as min_n_1 from table) t
group by id
```

Comment: sorry, I forget a important detail and edit my ask

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just aggregation:

```
select id, min(n_1), min(n_2), count(*)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: sorry, I forget a important detail and edit my ask